# Have installed Ubuntu to sd card but unable to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Afternoon all,

I've installed ubuntu to my SD card in my XPS 13 2in1. I am unable to boot from it due to the absence of grub I think - it just kicks me into windows.

Am currently booted from the livecd to try and resolve.

I have a messy NVME partition (thanks windows) called /dev/nvme0n1 with

```
EFI system partition
Microsoft reserved partition
Basic data partition
a 700mb NFTS partition
9.76gb nfts image
1.09 nfts image

(sorry if that is utterly irrelevant - just thought i'd add it)

The sd card is /dev/mmcblk01
with EFI system partition fat32 512mib
an ext4 partition 732mib
[encrypted] 114.94
unallocated 1.00mib

I did choose lfvs encryption when installing as I wish to use this so that explains the [encrypted]!

Any advice on what to try next please?



EFIMGR below

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* UEFI NVMe Storage
Boot0001* UEFI SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 0101d857a0dccfc14f1bae74869c0db5a5bc1a8b3fb55d9d1da13794f38c986f1c6b00000000000000000000d8d058feff1456009555810717289efb
Boot0002* UEFI SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 0101d857a0dccfc14f1bae74869c0db5a5bc1a8b3fb55d9d1da13794f38c986f1c6b00000000000000000000d8d058feff1456009555810717289efb 2
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* ubuntu
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* UEFI NVMe Storage PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,AC-E4-2E-61-90-03-6B-F7)/HD(1,GPT,6132f64a-29e7-454a-8778-d34c3909801f,0x800,0xfa000)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0001* UEFI SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 0101d857a0dccfc14f1bae74869c0db5a5bc1a8b3fb55d9d1da13794f38c986f1c6b00000000000000000000d8d058feff1456009555810717289efb   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(2,0)/CDROM(1,0x6a4,0x7d00)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0002* UEFI SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 0101d857a0dccfc14f1bae74869c0db5a5bc1a8b3fb55d9d1da13794f38c986f1c6b00000000000000000000d8d058feff1456009555810717289efb 2PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x38b1c112,0x6a4,0x1f40)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,6132f64a-29e7-454a-8778-d34c3909801f,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,581eaa35-eea2-4e1b-aeb0-297e5af3a203,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

Comment: Grub has nothing to do with booting it is for OS selection. Is this a PI device?

Comment: Is your SD Card a bootable option in BIOS? See https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-10/Dell-XPS-13-booting-from-SD-card/td-p/5077332.